# windows phone WebClient doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
```

When I try do to something like that I get an error

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'WebClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is available in WP8 Silverlight projects. I prefer to use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead.

```
public async Task<String> myFunction(){
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    String response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(
        new Uri("http://www.example.com")
    );
    return response;
}
```

To use the function you will again use await.

```
String data= await myFunction()
```

and so on...

You might need to install Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries from nuget

Comment: I don't use Silverlight projects, I'm using windows store apps

Comment: Does the new answer help?

Comment: Error 5 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<HtmlDocument>' this one now

Comment: Since HttpClient uses threads internally you have to use `async` on every function that calls `await`.